# How do I make a string of ","?

Tags: c#, string, syntax, literals

I tried:

```
string endtag = "\"","\"";
```

But that's not working. The string should be: `","`

The `"` is also part of the string not only the `,`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
string endtag = "\",\"";
```

To explain, the first `"` begins a string literal, the `\"` is an escape sequence for a `"` character, the `,` is a regular character, again, the `\"` is an escape sequence for a `"` character, then the final `"` closes the string literal.

You could also use a verbatim literal like this:

```
string endtag = @""",""";
```

Here the first `"` begins a string literal, and the `@` preceding it introduces it as a verbatim string literal. The next two `""` are a special escape sequence for a `"` character within a verbatim string literal, the `,` is a regular character, again, next two `""` are a special escape sequence for a `"` character, then the final `"` closes the string literal.

Comment: Apparently we both typed the same answer, char-by-char. I never seen an error as "This post appears to be a duplicate of ...".
However, you beat me!

Comment: @MarioVernari Ha, I've never seen that either.

Comment: @MarioVernari, SO probably needs to introduce a Quantum Entanglement Badge for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

try `string endtag = "\",\"";`  Alternatively you could try `string endtag = @""",""";` Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
string endtag = @""",""";
```

`@"..."` is a verbatim string literal

To use a `"` in this literal, it is doubled

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
   string endtag = "\",\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

String endtag = "\"" , "\"";

Answer (score 0):

`"` is an [`escape sequence character`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h21280bw.aspx).

If you want to put `"` in your string, you should use `\"` like this:

```
string endtag = "\",\"";
```

Or you can define [`verbatim string literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) using double *double quotation marks* (`""`) like;

```
string endtag = @""",""";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
string endtag="\",\"";
```